# Button not fetched from XML? Null Pointer

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception

```
newSubmitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newPlayerSubmit);
Log.v("heeelp",""+newSubmitButton);
```

Seems simple enough. I have a global `Button` variable called `newSubmitButton`. I fetch the Button from an xml file in the project (I promise, the button exists, i didn't mispell the name, etc.) I output the button in the next line, it is null. I try to give it an `onClickListener` and it throws a null pointer exception. How is this button null? I just instantiated it the line before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just instantiated it the line
>   before!

No you didn't,

```
newSubmitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newPlayerSubmit)
```

does not instantiate anything.  It simply retrieves the button from the active view.  If the button isn't part of the active view (perhaps the layout hasn't been inflated yet?) then your button reference will be null.  Are you calling this code in your Activity's `onCreate()` method?  Have you called `setContentView()` before executing the code in question?

Answer (score 1):

Besides misspelling the name, you might have left out a call to `setContentView()`.

(If that's not the issue, please post more code.)

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to setContentView() higher up? Just because R.java contains it doesn't mean it's attached to your view.